# Javascript: Looping Through Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of images that I want to loop through infinitely but I can't seem to get the logic down, this is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/RwjFX/4/

```js
var imagesArray = ["http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/e/ef/025Pikachu_Pokemon_Mystery_Dungeon_Red_and_Blue_Rescue_Teams.png/revision/latest?cb=20150105233050",
"http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png",
"http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full/001.png",
"http://www.pokemonxy.com/_ui/img/_en/art/Fennekin-Pokemon-X-and-Y.jpg",
"http://www.pokemon20.com/assets/img/mythical/arceus/poke_arceus.png"];

var count = 0;
  
  
    var loopImages = function(count){

            $('#firstStar').fadeIn(1500, function(){

            if (count=0){
            $('img').attr('src', imagesArray[1]);
            }

             $('#firstStar').delay(4000).fadeOut(1500, loopImages(count));           
           });
           count++;
           console.log('Ending Count:'+count);
      }
   
   
   loopImages(count); //Step 1: Initiate Loop, passing count, starting at 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.kingdomhearts.com/2_8/images/logos/kingdom_hearts_birth_by_sleep_logo.png" id="firstStar">
```

Comment: You need to check your operators...

Comment: arrays are 0 based in JS

Comment: Wow, great help guys, thanks, I definitely solved my answer with those comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the code to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/RwjFX/5/

In particular, see usage of the [modulo (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator and the [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll research this.

Comment: Pete - how do you avoid the stackoverflow on the recursive call?

Comment: @akaphenom :D ...By using a loop instead of recursion, of course. But hey, after all, this is stackoverflow.com

Comment: @akaphenom There is also an integer overflow if someone is looking at Pokemons for a number of years (1999314903.0690?)

Comment: Yeah, but  I love the modulo - it alleviates the stupid (count == array.length) count = 0 bit

Comment: Hm, now that I think of it perhaps there is no stack overflow, `.fadeOut`'s callback is called in a later frame, and the `loopImages` returns without waiting for that.